# CSS 3D flip jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

When I `mouseover` over the any box, the facebook, twitter video reel etc. looks as a mirror reflection after the flip.  It is only in chrome. Whereas in Firefox it is running as expected.

Here is my webpage [**http://luutaa.co.in/TMcollection/**](http://luutaa.co.in/TMcollection/)

Please suggest me a solution to resolve it?

Comment: i am shearing the link of this. http://luutaa.co.in/TMcollection/

Comment: You have to be clearer as to what your actual question is. The site looks fine on both Chrome 28 and Firefox 22.

Comment: according to link, top of the images text in white box like facebook, video reel, pinterest etc. its look mirror after flip in chrome.

Comment: i just want to hide mirror text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy fix would be to add this to your CSS:

```
.flipIt .fbbtn{
    display:none;
}
```

Though it produces some flickering when you hover out the boxes, if you feel that's not acceptable you may need to implement @user1671639's answer and probably use a timer to show the button only after the CSS animation is complete

Comment: thank you so much, I got your solution.

Comment: @VijayPandey you should mark the answer you think was best as "accepted", you can do so by clicking the green check mark next to it (below the voting counter)

Comment: can i mark two answer simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

you want to hide the mirror text, then try like this

when you do a **`mouseover`**, hide the `.fbbtn`block

```
$('.fbbtn').hide();
```

and make its **`callback`** to show it

```
$('.fbbtn').show();
```

Hope you got an idea.

**Update:** Upon further investigation, I found the right place to apply this

```
$('.thumb').hover(function () {
   $(this).find('.fbbtn').hide();  //HIDE UPON HOVER
    $(this).find('.thumb-detail').stop().animate({
        bottom: 0
    }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
},

function () {
    $(this).find('.fbbtn').show();  //SHOW IT IN CALLBACK
    $(this).find('.thumb-detail').stop().animate({
        bottom: ($(this).height() * -1)
    }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
});
```

Comment: I would place the `show()` inside the `animate()` callback

Comment: @koala_dev yes, it will be good and smooth.  If you find some time, feel free to edit my answer or let me do it.  Anyway thanks for the pointers :)

Comment: And after further review it appears that that hover function is only used when the browser does not support CSS 3D transitions, the same concept needs to be applied to the `$('.thumb.flip').hover(`

Comment: ... or outside in a separate handler like the OP seems to have done

Comment: Excellent thank you so much it the is real solution. thank you so much again.

Comment: @VijayPandey I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: @VijayPandey If you think it is an opt solution for your problem, you can mark it as answer:)

Comment: Can i mark two answer simultaneously ?

Comment: @VijayPandey :) Not possible.

Comment: @VijayPandey I don't mind you mark the otherone as answer, its pretty elegant one.  The motto here is Good answer that helped you :)

Comment: thank you your answer is also helpful for me. i shall use it another time.